# How can I make a template of another template?

Tags: c#, class, opencv, templates, inheritance

I am using the C# opencv class and I want to make a sub class of the image type.

I would normally use the class like this:

```
public Image<Gray, byte> grayImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(1920, 1080);
```

This is the subclass

```
public class MyImage<T> where T : Emgu.CV.IColor
{
    public MyImage()
    {
        Image<T, byte> ree = new Image<T, byte>(1920, 1080);
    }
}
```

It gives me this error

> CS0453    The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use
> it as parameter 'TColor' in the generic type or method 'Image<TColor,
> TDepth>'

This is the definition of IColor

```
public interface IColor
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The equivalent MCvScalar value
    MCvScalar MCvScalar { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Get the dimension of the color type
    int Dimension { get; }
}
```

How can I make a sub template of this template type by making IColor non-nullable?

Comment: `where T : struct, Emgu.CV.IColor`?

Comment: I tried `where T : struct` earlier and has the same issue. Didn't know I had to use two definitions.  Thanks

Comment: `Image<TColor, TDepth>` <-- what is it , can you post that ?

Comment: you missing `new()` this where , look my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class Image<TColor, TDepth> : CvArray<TDepth>, 
    IEquatable<Image<TColor, TDepth>>, IInputOutputArray, IInputArray, 
    IDisposable, IOutputArray, IInputArrayOfArrays, IOutputArrayOfArrays
where TColor : struct, new(), IColor
where TDepth : new()
```

Because Your `<T>` need tran to `<TColor>` , So you `<T>` need same with `<TColor>`. like this

```
public class MyImage<T> where T : struct, new(), Emgu.CV.IColor
```